# Kombu - TypeError: Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror, kombu

I have been using `Kombu` for sometime now - and today when I readied a new machine for deployment, I am getting `TypeError` on `import` from `kombu`:

```
>>> import kombu
>>> from kombu import Connection, Exchange, Queue, Producer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/__init__.py", line 81, in __getattr__
    module = __import__(object_origins[str(name)], None, None, [str(name)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 15, in <module>
    from kombu import exceptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from amqp import ChannelError, ConnectionError, ResourceError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .basic_message import Message      # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/basic_message.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .serialization import GenericContent
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/serialization.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .exceptions import FrameSyntaxError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/exceptions.py", line 264, in <module>
    str(_method_name)
TypeError: Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the known issue of kombu https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/622